# How to use foreach in constraint in multidimensional array

Tags: system-verilog

I have two signals that are related. `signalToConstraint[i][j][k]` is should be less than `signalLimit[i]` for all `i` values. I have tried to code below, and it works for index 0, but for the rest (1 to 7) it is not working.

```
rand logic [7:0][1:0][15:0][3:0] signalToConstraint;
rand logic [7:0][3:0] signalLimit;

constraint c_testConstrain {
    foreach (signalToConstraint[i]) {
        foreach (signalToConstraint[i][j]) {
            foreach (signalToConstraint[i][j][k]) {
                signalToConstraint[i][j][k] < signalLimit[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just to make it clearer. For example, I want `signalToConstraint[4][1][12] < signalLimit[4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` syntax you show is generally not acceptable. Some tools confuse

```
foreach (signalToConstraint[i]) {
     foreach (signalToConstraint[i][j]) {
```

And treat the `[i]` in the second line as a new iterator, and not the iterated value from the previous line.

The correct way to write this is using a comma separated list of iterators

```
constraint c_testConstrain {
  foreach (signalToConstraint[i,j,k])
    signalToConstraint[i][j][k] < signalLimit[i];  
}
```